# Erro Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI] no GCC

Tags: android, terminal, gcc

Eu já fiz de tudo, instalei o GCC C4droid pelo Google Store, já instalei o Android Terminal Emulator e também já root ei e liberei o acesso ao `$su`.
Porem quando eu tento instalar o GCC usando o comando `PM install GCC` ele aparece escrito `pkg: gcc; Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]`.
Se alguém souber de alguma solução.

> apt-get e o site sobre instalação do NDK e SDk no site da Android não da certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certa vez tive o mesmo problema ao instalar um `APK pelo shell android`.

- `Primeiro erro que eu consegui foi: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI`

  ```
  $ pm install myApp.apk
      pkg: myApp.apk
  Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]
  ```
- Isso é porque você precisa dar o caminho completo para o apk, como:

  ```
  $ pm install /sdcard/myApp.apk
  ```

> Faça o seguinte:

1. Refactor -> Rename
2. Project -> Clean

### Crie uma cópia "limpa" do seu projeto.

Comment: Hmm compreendi, mas nesse caso onde eu posso estar pegando esse arquivo?

Comment: Como sugeri, faça uma limpeza do seu projeto, pois parece haver um erro gerado pela IDE.

Comment: Exatamente is so por que nao tem nada compilado pois nao tem IDE so o terminals e gostaria de instalar o gcc por ele para usar o terminal para programar pelo cell como we fosse no linux

Comment: Mano, o problema é exatamente no caminho errado que você dar para a instalação com o `PM install GCC`

Comment: hmm entendi agora apareceu assim `[INSTALL_FAILED_ALREDY_EXISTS]` mas nem chegei a instalar

Comment: Tudo certo??????

Comment: Então acredito que SIM ma's eu apnea nao descobri o commando para compilar